# Access a hash value from another ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, hash, key-value

I have currently 2 APIs that require 2 different credentials. I want to commit my changes to `Github` but I dont want those credentials to be seen hence I decided to keep all my credentials in a `hash` in a separate `ruby` file and then want to access it in my script. At the same time, adding that file to `.gitignore`. But I am stuck in accessing that `hash` from my current script.

Here is my `credentials.rb`:

```
credentials = { 
    APIKEY: '12'
    PASSWORD: '34'
    sid: '45'
    token: '56'
}
```

Here is my `main.rb`:

```
class ApisController < ApplicationController

  def api
    url = "https://#{credentials[APIKEY]}:#{credentials[PASSWORD]}@test"
  end

end
```

I am not sure how do I call that hash in `main.rb`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't just add these references to your secrets.yml and then add the true values to the ENV?

Comment: @Austio I have added values to ENV already but how can I access it from `yml` file.. just directly like this: `#{APIKEY}` if for example, I add: `APIKEY: "123"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways you can do this:

1. There is the conventional & **convenient** way to do this in Rails. Add all your private credentials in an `.env`ironment file.
2. Access a hash value from another ruby script that you `gitignore`.
3. Or you can do it an even longer way, if you so insist.

**First way:** Use environment variables directly within the file where you need them. If you need them in yaml:

`your_yaml_file.yml`

```
 credentials_or_whatever:
       APIKEY: <%= ENV['API_KEY'] %>
       PASSWORD: <%= ENV['API_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Or if you need them in `main.rb`:

```
class ApisController < ApplicationController

  def api
    url = "https://#{credentials['APIKEY']}:#{credentials['PASSWORD']}@test"
  end

end
```

**Second way:** If for some reason you must use a hash that you `gitignore` instead of using just an environment file, then your `credentials.rb`contains your credential that you later access where you need them. `gitignore`d file:

```
credentials = { 
    "APIKEY": "12",
    "PASSWORD": "34"
    "sid": "45"
    "token": "56"
}
```

Then your `main.rb`:

```
class ApisController < ApplicationController

  def api
    url = "https://#{credentials["APIKEY"]}:#{credentials["PASSWORD"]}@test"
  end

end
```

**Third way:** Add your private credentials in environment variables and also then use them to create a hash that you gitignore:

Your `credentials.rb` file:

```
credentials = { 
    "APIKEY": ENV['APIKEY'],
    "PASSWORD": ENV['PASSWORD'],
    "sid": ['SID'],
    "token": ENV['TOKEN']
}
```

In first and second cases, your environment variables file might look like this:

`.env`(in your rails root folder):

```
APIKEY = 12
PASSWORD = 34
SID = 1234
TOKEN = 5678
```

I hope that helps to explain!

Comment: If I do use environment variables then how can I access in my credentials.rb

Comment: Why would you create a hash in `credentials.rb` and then also use environment variables to hide your credentials? Just gitignore your `.env` file. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I am finding the best way to achieve this. I want to learn both the ways to do it as well.

Comment: and where do I add `credentials code that you mentioned` ? which file?

Comment: I have expanded my answer per your comment. I hope it helps.